# Is Entity Framework 7 going to work with .NET Framework 4.5?

Tags: .net-4.5, entity-framework-core

Is Entity Framework 7.0 RTM release going to work with .NET Framework 4.5?

According to comments in [issue 2443](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2443) EF 7.0 was supposed to support Mono which requires 4.5 version of framework.

Recent code changes suggest an upgrade to 4.5.1, is this going to stay that way?

Comment: Try commenting on the GitHub issue you referenced to see if you can get a more official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest versions of Mono have updated to the Microsoft reference source, so compiling against 4.5.1 should work just fine on Mono now.

Answer (score 1):

EF.Relational now (RC2) requires .NET 4.5.1